# php: shellscript running before screen-output

Tags: php, bash

I'm currently putting together a small web-based GUI to generate kickstart-scripts. I got a confirmation page that's sending the relevant data via POST to the PHP-page where the actual shell script is called to build the iso. So far it's working, but the page seems to execute the script before it outputs anything else (for example, the 'echo' I put in at the beginning of the page ...), and I'm absolutely clueless why. Would anyone care to enlighten me?

Here's the code to the PHP-page that's executing the shell script ...

```
echo 'Generating your ISO; this might take a while...';
sleep(20);

if (!isset($_POST['auth'])) {
        $ad = 'N';
        }
else {
        $ad = 'Y';
}

if (!isset($_POST['oracle'])) {
        $oracle = 'N';
        }
else {
        $oracle = 'Y';
        }

if ((!isset($_POST['ip'])) or (!isset($_POST['hostname'])) or (!isset($_POST['rhsel'])) or (!isset($_POST['submit'])) or (!isset($_POST['gw'])) or (!isset($_POST['nm']))) {
        die('Please use the correct form !');
}

if (isset($_POST['ip'])) {
        $ip = trim($_POST['ip']);
        }

if (isset($_POST['gw'])) {
        $gw = trim($_POST['gw']);
        }

if (isset($_POST['nm'])) {
        $nm = trim($_POST['nm']);
        }

if (isset($_POST['hostname'])) {
        $hostname = trim($_POST['hostname']);
        }

if (isset($_POST['rhsel'])) {
        $rhsel = $_POST['rhsel'];
        }
passthru("/usr/bin/sudo /data/skripte/webconfig.sh $rhsel $oracle $ad $ip $gw $nm $hostname 2>&1");
```

Comment: You have `sleep(20)` after the `echo` statement, so unless the generation of the ISO is kicked off asynchronously before the sleep statement you are waiting 20 seconds for nothing. Could you post the shell script please, or at least what its final output is?

Comment: I tried the whole thing without the sleep(20) too, with the same result;
the shell-script is putting together an ISO with various parameters I collect with a form in the page that's POSTing to the one in question.
The script itself seems to be too long by about 6000 characters, and outputs as intended, means, it completes successfully.
The problem is that it starts without the php-page doing any output, meaning it just loads, then outputs the whole page (including the echo at line 1) at once...
here's the scripts output:

Comment: Generating your ISO; this might take a while...6.7 vlpooot201.at.inside RedHat Version: 6.7 FQDN: vlpooot201.at.inside Size of boot image is 4 sectors -> No emulation 3.55% done, estimate finish Mon Feb 22 14:13:00 2016[...] 99.01% done, estimate finish Mon Feb 22 14:13:01 2016 Total translation table size: 2048 Total rockridge attributes bytes: 2515 Total directory bytes: 6742 Path table size(bytes): 56 Max brk space used 12000 141411 extents written (276 MB) Downloadlink: CORRECT DL-LINK; FINISHED

Comment: Are you expecting the script to output the actual ISO binary? Or just output regarding the creation of the ISO?

Comment: the output of the shell is alright, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. 
the problem lies with php itself. i'm at the summary.php, click submit to get to the iso.php (code in OP); browser stays on summary.php, loads iso.php and outputs all the content of iso.php only after the script is finished, instead of loading iso.php right away and displaying the output of the script while it's working...

Comment: In which case I can provide a formal answer to your problem. I'm afraid that behaviour is just not possible. See answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

PHP scripts accessed via a browser are request-response, meaning all processing is done on the server prior to headers and content being sent to the client. This means you will not get a continually updating output like you would see on the command line. There is no way around this. Sorry.